# Saving a static Context variable in Application class

Tags: android

I've wondering if it's okay to do this: whenever we pass a `Context` variable around, could we just get a singleton reference from the Application class instead

For example here is a subclass of `Application` class with a single static variable pointing to its own instance

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static mApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

        mApp = this;
    }
}
```

Then when we need to pass a `Context` to a method from somewhere, can we just do

```
foo(App.mApp);
```

Isn't it okay to treat `Context` as an application variable?

Comment: It will work fine, I have work on it.

Comment: this is the best article regarding context: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

storing a static application context won't do any harm, only if you know what you are doing and where you can use it!

Comment: This works fine as long as you can use the application context and don't need an activity context.

Comment: @Henry why aren't all `Context` variables created equal? Don't they all extend from the 'Context` class?

Comment: @the_prole they have the same interface but are different objects and calling methods can give different results. For example the theme used for an activity may be different than the global application theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on the context in which you are using it. Many times a context is meant to keep hold of things until it's lifescope is complete and then allow garbage collection to take back whatever it was owning.

Other times the context needs to be an activity to handle life cycle call backs such as onNewIntent or onActivityResult.

Keeping a static instance in the parent is just a shortcut to avoid having to getApplication() and cast it as your type of application. I typically make a method for MyApplication.getApplication().doSomething which will return it's own reference of itself as opposed to ((MyApplication)getApplication()).doSomething

Just seems cleaner for coding purposes. But I would be very leary of using the application context everywhere you need a context, it will come back to bite you eventually.

But yes you can certainly store yourself as a static variable to be shared, I do it in most applications, but typically for a specific shortcut purpose of clean maintainable code, not for cheating on getting context from various crevices.